# UITableViewCell willDisplayCell method conundrum

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Whenever I create a new cell, strange magic occurs. If I exit the view controller later (with the data all saved up), and come back to the view controller again (with the data reloaded, etc.), everything is ok (but if I stay in the view controller it is messed up)

Now let me describe this strange magic:

- I have a custom UITableViewCell
- When the indexPath is even, a blue circle exists in it
- When the indexPath is odd, a green rectangle exists in it

However, when a new cell is created, it has both a green rectangle and a blue circle in it, how is this possible?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CustomCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (cell.blueCircle)    cell.blueCircle = nil;
    if (cell.greenRect)   cell.greenRect = nil;    
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        NSLog(@"Even indexPath: %@", indexPath);
        //some of the code not shown here creates a blue circle
        [cell addSubview:cell.blueCircle];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Odd indexPath: %@", indexPath);
        //some of the code not shown here creates a green rectangle
        [cell addSubview:cell.greenRect];
    } 
}
```

Note that I only get one NSLog, either an odd or an even one, so why do I get two shapes instead of just one?

I have a feeling that, one of the shapes is getting carried over somehow (not sure how this works) from the previous cell to the new cell, before this message is called, but I do have lazy "nilization" to combat this.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the cells are pulled from the reuse queue, they aren't completely redrawn unless you tell them to redraw using [-setNeedsDisplayInRect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCCHHI) and pass in the dirty rect that needs to be redrawn.  Otherwise, you'll need to draw over the blueCircle's rect when you draw the greenSquare's rect and vice versa.

I believe what is happening is that the green square being drawn in the past, the cell is added to the reuse queue after it scrolls offscreen, the cell is then pulled from the reuse queue to be populated with new data, then the blue circle happens to be drawn on the current pass but the rect the green square is drawn on was never invalidated and redrawn.

Comment: This is awesome, I had a feeling it was something like this. I just did not understand what exactly it was. This explanation was really helpful for a first time iOSer like me. :)  However, rdelmar's solution is better than yours. So I am not sure, who I should give the chocolate chip cookie (checkmark) to? @Andrew

Comment: I have decided to choose yours as the winner, but I gave upvotes to both of you

Answer (score 3):

Setting cell.blueCircle to nil sets the pointer to nil, but doesn't remove the blueCircle. Since the blue circle is a subview of the cell, the cell has a strong pointer to it. You need to remove it from its superview.

```
[cell.blueCircle removeFromSuperview];
[cell.greenRect removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. :)  I actually tried this after seeing Andrew's answer which helped me understand where I went wrong. However, your solution is better than his. So I am not sure, who I should give the chocolate chip cookie (checkmark) to? Maybe enhance your explanation to compete with Andrew's. @rdelmar

Comment: @GangstaGraham, Andrew's post actually answers your question about how this can happen, mine just tells you how to fix it, so choose however you like.

Comment: I have decided to choose Andrew's as the winner because he helped me understand the situation better, but I gave upvotes to both of you, plus you already have your fair share of points :P  @rdelmar